# Python Selenium Webdriver Opera Browser Opening Properly But Only Displays "data:," on the Address Bar and a Empty Screen

Tags: python, selenium

```html
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Opera()

driver.get('https://google.com')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="lst-ib"]')
element.send_keys("Hello World")
```

The Selenium webdriver Opera browser opens properly but only displays "data:," on the address bar and a empty screen.

I used the same code and IE, Edge, Chrome, and Firefox work well.

Comment: Try upgrading Opera driver version

Comment: Everything is up to date, the only problem might be the opera webdriver .exe file, https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be using Python 2.7 or older version.

If you do not know how to do this make sure you study/learn about virtual env.

Also the [Opera Webdriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/releases) that you download from Git works on an older version of Opera.

Be sure you download the [Opera 27 version](http://www.opera.com/download/guide/?os=windows&list=all) for your OS.

The tricky part is when you open Opera it will immediately try to download its update. Be sure once you install it, that you turn off your PC in order for it to not update. When you restart go into your computer's "Program Files" folder and locate Opera. Inside that folder there will be another folder named "27.0.1689.76" or whatever 27 version you are running make sure you find the updater.exe file and right click (be sure you are an admin) and delete the file.

After go to your env and find the downloaded Python 2.7 file and open the scripts folder. Add the download Opera webdriver from git in the scripts forlder.(not the Opera Launcher).

Opera should now work with selenium!